# Obtaining PHP Remote Address Info from URL

Tags: php, ip-address

I am new to PHP and keen to learn and I was wondering if people could please let me know how to obtain phpinfo information, specifically under the Apache Environment, the variable REMOTE_ADDR?

I basically provide a user with a url to a partcular website, which ultimately returns them a csv file where they can either save/delete or cancel.

On the same URL, I was wondering if I can call a PHP function to obtain this information or even better, call the variable directly from the URL?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain REMOTE_ADDR from the [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) global array

`$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];`

As for the URL, you can use [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) to pass data through a URL.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could understand it, you can get it like this:

```
$addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo $addr;
```

And if you want to give this info to anyone, you can put it in URL like this:

```
<a href="whateverpage.php?addr=<?php echo $addr;?>">Link</a>
```

Now the address will be there into the URL (query string).

Comment: This is the superior response as you should not use double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use [getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) or $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] can get the variable you want.

The [fopen()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) can be used for open a file in a remote host, for example:

```
$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/data.csv", "r");
```

so you can open a csv file in the remote server via http protocol.