# PHP: how to check ip address of the script invoker

Tags: php, ip-address

I need to add an if statement on top of my php script in order to check the ip of the script invoker:

```
if (invoker_ip = "123.123.123.123") {
    .. code here ..
}
```

the script is just a script.php file on my server

thanks

Comment: you have accepted (and going to use I assume) a misleading and harmful code, dude

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Obtaining PHP Remote Address Info from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235083/obtaining-php-remote-address-info-from-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
$invoker_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Nevertheless this value will not be relevant if user is behind a proxy.
The real ip probably can be found in HTTP header like HTTP_CLIENT_IP or HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR but can't be trusted. (header are easy to modify)

Comment: most common mistake all noobs do. You're mixing IP address with HTTP headers. too sad to see it upvoted and accepted.

Comment: @grunk ... it would be nice to know what the code was BEFORE you edited it ... someone indicated that your answer was dangerous. But since then you have changed it. And now I do not know if your edited answer is the old dangerous answer, or the new fixed and safe answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ip = '123.123.132.132';

if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] === $ip) {
    // This will only excexuted if the IP matches
    echo 'IP does match :)';
} else {
    echo 'IP does not match!';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
invoker_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Answer (score 2):

Ask [$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) but beware of proxies.